# Open window, call window.print(), print it (silently) and close the tab

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, printing

I work with logistics;
There we need to print some labels. It used to give us a PDF with all the labels in the order that we insert it. But now is somewhat random, so I'm working on making it print in "our" order.

I've managed store all the labels in the order that they are inserted and the open, one by one, by (in a For statement):

```
var actualLabel = open("link to print" + labels[i]);
actualLabel.print();
```

So the browser opens ALL the print tabs, then I just 'Enter + Ctrl+W' until it finishes everything.

What I wanted is:
-I insert the label on the page (Done)
-It opens the label print page in background (can't manage to open it without focusing on the new tab)
-Calls the print() on that window (Done)
From here on I can't manage to do:
-Confirms the impression with the printer that I want
-Closes the tab

All it without losing the original Tab's focus.

I couldn't manage to open the tabs silently and confirms the print.

Comment: Your issue with losing tab focus could probably be solved, by not opening the documents in new tabs, but in iframes that are part of the current document, and then printing those.

Comment: But printing without any confirmation is likely not going to be that easy – for obvious reasons, because if that was possibly just willy-nilly, then the last five websites you visited would probably already have sent several meters worth of “buy v1a6ra h3re!!1” to your printer. This has been asked before (https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+print+without+confirmation+popup+site:stackoverflow.com), but I would not rely on any of the older solutions still working. This might need a custom browser extension or something like that.

Comment: I will search for those iFrames.

Comment: About the silent printing. I've managed to do so, buy the way I founded changes the browser's configuration Globaly, and we don't have only one Printer, so we would need to change the main Printer everytime. But maybe it's the best solution that I have